# Взаимосвязь js и php через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, сервер, клиент

Здравствуйте.Помогите, пожалуйста, в решении следующего вопроса. Необходимо на сервер отправить данные посредством ajax, на сервере средствами php обработать и вернуть обратно. Я сделал ajax запрос, но сервер выдает ошибку 502. Установлен денвер. Я не понимаю как будет мой скрипт php слушать запрос. Интересует сам момент взаимодействия. Подскажите где можно почитать, или посоветуйте книгу. В инете много скриптов обработки запроса. Но как чтобы php услышал запрос, получил и вернул ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, как-то так:

**index.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    $text = (!empty($_POST['mytext'])) ? 'MD5: <b>'.md5($_POST['mytext']).'</b>' : 'Текст не передан';
    echo $text;
    exit();
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST AJAX</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="mytext" placeholder="Введите какой-нибудь текст">
            <button type="button" id="send-mytext">SEND</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="result">
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#send-mytext').click(function(){
                    var blockResult = $('#result');

                    $(blockResult).html('Продождите...');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/index.php?ajax',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({
                            mytext: $('#mytext').val()
                        }),
                        success: function( answer ){
                            $(blockResult).html( answer );
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Но я бы рекомендовал вам поизучать эту тему подробней.